# conditional formatting in pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I am trying to color the cells in one column (E) based on the value of the cells in another column (C) but when I create a new rule I see that the condition applies to all the cells in the Table and they are all compared to a single one selected value
[image]

Any idea Please?

regards